# Power/Voltage Conditioner From Portable Generator To Boiler Computer Advice

Tags: power-supply, power

I have a portable 5.8kW generator that is about 13 years old, well maintained and with only about 5 service hours on it. I run it every couple months and put loads on it as well.

I have a new Navien Wall Hung Condensing Boiler which I want to be able to power in the event we lose power. The boiler has a computer and other electronic components in it.

Since, during the winter, the boiler is my first priority (provides domestic hot water and baseboard heat) I want to be able to power it from the generator.

I've read that the profile of the sine wave coming out of some generators could be detrimental to some electronics. Of course the A/C goes through a power supply for the electronics, but I would like to get some advice on this overall.

Comment: If the voltage is within range, including any overshoot when any thermostat turns off, I’d estimate 99.9 % success rate for said electronics to operate on your generator. Please measure the voltage though.

Comment: You should provide some evidence that your generator may have an issue providing suitable power.  Otherwise, this question will likely result only in anecdotal answers.  Large scale power conditioning is expensive (like an online UPS of sorts).  Many power 
 conditioning widgets you see on the web are scams.

Comment: Thank you. The output of my generator has always been in spec. Is there a mechanism for me to ask for general help here? I.E. I want to follow a thread. Not sure if you will see this comment. Do I need to add your names? Thank you. Can I get email notifications a question I've posted has been replied to? Thanks again.